# How to remove the unused output in Excel destination in SSIS package

Tags: excel, ssis

I have a SSIS task that saves a SQL query to an Excel file on disk.  In the query, there is a varchar variable.  I need to have a step to transform the varchar to a unicode.  For example, I have a column "Name" in the SQL query. This transform step will finally generate a column ("Copy of Name" or "Data Conversion of Name") in the step of Excel Destination.  Then I do the mapping from input ("Copy of Name") to output ("Name").  I do not do the mapping of "Copy of Name" in the output, but it will be automatically listed as output.

When I run the SSIS, it will save two columns in the Excel file, "Name" and "copy of name".  Clearly I do not need  "copy of name", and wish to get rid of it.  Is there any way to do this?  Thank you in advance!

Comment: Cant you just remove it in the mappings tab in the excel destination?

Comment: Yes, the solution is to remove the unused columns in the create table command. Thank you very much!